# My civ icon now asking DX9 or DX11

Tags: civilization-5

I had it setup that when I execute CIV 5 that it would load the DirectX 11 version without asking.

It is now asking using the following dialogue (note i am also showing how it can create an icon).

[image]

I have tried deleting my desktop icon and right clicking to save a Civ 5 DX11 icon to my desktop.

How can I get it to load the DX11 without asking (as per the printscreen above.

Here is my shortcut string:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\
    sid meier's civilization v\Launcher.exe" /dx11
```

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8355/how-can-i-stop-civilization-5-from-asking-me-twice-which-directx-mode-to-play-in

Comment: Thank you for pointing that question out. None of the solutions presented have worked :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been resolved by the latest patch.

You do have to create a new icon.

So when executing the game and you are presented with DX9 or DX11. Right click on DX11 and create a shortcut on the desktop. You can delete the older shortcut and use the new one now.